# Copying NSDictionary value in UITextview

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code, where the global variable `var fullDict = ""` stores dictionary of values.

```
let resultsArray = dicData["value"] as! NSDictionary
for (x, y) in resultsArray {
        self.fullDict += "(\(x): \(y))\n"
}
```

I want to print this value as it is in UITextview. I tried,

```
userResult_txtView.text = self.fullDict
```

but, this is showing build error as "use of unresolved identifier userResult_txtView" and also "use of unresolved identifier self"

Could you please tell me how to copy that value (self.fullDict) in UITextview? I am using Swift 3.

Code starts like this,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var table:UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var userID_txtField:UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var userName_txtField:UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var userAccountNo_txtField:UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var userAccType_txtField:UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var userAccAddress_txtField:UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var userResult_txtView:UITextView!

    var mainArray:[Any] = []
    var fullDict = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
```

Comment: are you sure that both `userResult_txtView` and `fullDict` exist? can you show the rest of the code of that particular view controller?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. Where is `fullDict` defined? Is it an instance variable of your view controller? What class & method contains the two code fragments that you posted? The error you're reporting suggests that the line `userResult_txtView.text = self.fullDict` is in a class that does not have a property `fullDict`.

Comment: I showed already that, var fullDict = "" global variable gets filled.

Comment: Another is IBOutlet, @IBOutlet var userResult_txtView:UITextView!

Comment: The error is more of Dictionary couldn't copy as String there.

Comment: `...Array ... as! ...Dictionary`, very confusing. Once again **do not use NSDictionary in Swift, use native types**

Comment: ok any examples for native types.

Comment: Compiler never says just "use of unresolved identifier", it tells about specific identifier. What is it? `fullDict` or `userResult_txtView`?

Comment: It says "use of unresolved identifier userResult_txtView"  and also "use of unresolved identifier self"

Comment: The [Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) is full of examples

Comment: where do you call `userResult_txtView.text = self.fullDict`?

Comment: @Stella, I assume that you're trying to assign `fullDict` to `userResult_txtView.text` outside of `ViewController` methods

Comment: I call userResult_txtView.text = self.fullDict in a separate function. func resultUpdate ()
{ userResult_txtView.text = self.fullDict }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, you have put the line:

```
userResult_txtView.text = self.fullDict
```

somewhere outside of the scope of the `ViewController`. That's the reason why it tells you that it cannot resolve identifier `userResult_txtView` and `self` - to use `self.fullDict` and `userResult_txtView` you have to use that line inside of an instance method of the `ViewController`, so e.g.:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    ...

    func showFullDict() {
        userResult_txtView.text = self.fullDict
    }
}
```

Comment: It is like that only.

Comment: @Stella that's why I have asked you to show the whole viewController.. where is the `resultUpdate()` defined? show the whole code

Comment: You are absolutely right! It was outside of it. Now it is working perfect. My Bad, Sorry